# How to resolve parsing error for CSV file in Logstash

Tags: ruby, csv, logstash, filebeat

I am using Filebeat to send a CSV file to Logstash and then up to Kibana, however I am getting a parsing error when the CSV file is picked up by Logstash.

This is the contents of the CSV file:

```
time    version id  score   type

May 6, 2020 @ 11:29:59.863  1 2 PPy_6XEBuZH417wO9uVe  _doc
```

The logstash.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns =>["time","version","id","index","score","type"]
      }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

Filebeat.yml:

```
filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

- type: log

  # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
  enabled: true

  # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
  paths:
    - /etc/test/*.csv
    #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*
```

and the error in Logstash:

```
[2020-05-27T12:28:14,585][WARN ][logstash.filters.csv     ][main] Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"time,version,id,score,type,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,", :exception=>#<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected LogStash::Timestamp)>}
[2020-05-27T12:28:14,586][WARN ][logstash.filters.csv     ][main] Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"\"May 6, 2020 @ 11:29:59.863\",1,2,PPy_6XEBuZH417wO9uVe,_doc,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,", :exception=>#<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected LogStash::Timestamp)>}
```

I do get some data in Kibana but not what I want to see.

[image]

Comment: Hello Calum Price, I have noticed your column names, and i couldn't help but notice you are using all of logstash reserved field names: "@timestamp", "@version", "_id" and the rest... Another thing is, @timestamp field should be of timestamp format, your timestamp has a '@' sign in the middle which is not according to the `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601`. try changing the column name or changing the timestamp format to fit ISO8601. Lastly your timestamp has a ',' after the day and it can cause logstash to split the data falsely.

Comment: @eladyanai Updated the fields in the csv. Similar error. [2020-05-27T12:58:24,932][WARN ][logstash.filters.csv     ][main] Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"time,version,id,score,type,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,", :exception=>#<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected LogStash::Timestamp)>}

Comment: I am not sure this is related, but you have extra column on your logstash filter called "_index", and in your csv example it is not existing. regarding the timestamp error, can you please provide me with the latest csv file? and logstash conf? thanks.

Comment: CSV: time version id score type
May 6 2020  11:29:59.863 1 2 3 4                                                                                                                       input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}




filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","                                                                                           
      columns =>["time","version","id","score","type"]
      }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}

Comment: @eladyanai simplified the CSV for testing

Comment: Hey. I have tested this locally and managed to get it to work. apparently you set the seperator to `,` but except to the timestamp you have no `,` in your CSV file. either change the seperator to `\t` or split the csv using `,` with no spaces.

Comment: Your "CSV" file isn't CSV, "comma-separated values", instead it appears to be TSV, "tab-separated values", which is similar, but it's important to keep the language correct when talking about these things. The CSV class can handle TSV if you change the separator value. Also, please do not put data or essential information for the question in comments. Add that to the question, incorporating it as if the new data was initially there for readability. Using comments forces us to read every comment and try to piece the question together from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get it to work locally. the mistakes I have noticed so far were:

1. Using ES reserved fields like `@timestamp`, `@version`, and more.
2. The timestamp was not in ISO8601 format. It had an `@` sign in the middle.
3. Your filter set the separator to `,` but your CSV real separator is `"\t"`.
4. According to the error you can see it is trying to also work on your titles line, I suggest you remove it from the CSV or use the [`skip_header`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-skip_header) option.

Below is the logstash.conf file I used:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "C:/work/elastic/logstash-6.5.0/config/test.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
    } 
}
filter { 
    csv { 
        separator => ","
        columns =>["time","version","id","score","type"]
    } 
} 
output { 
    elasticsearch { 
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "csv-test" 
    } 
}
```

The CSV file I used:

```
May 6 2020 11:29:59.863,1,PPy_6XEBuZH417wO9uVe,_doc
May 6 2020 11:29:59.863,1,PPy_6XEBuZH417wO9uVe,_doc
May 6 2020 11:29:59.863,1,PPy_6XEBuZH417wO9uVe,_doc
May 6 2020 11:29:59.863,1,PPy_6XEBuZH417wO9uVe,_doc
```

From my Kibana:

[image]

Comment: That looks like it should do the trick but getting the same error when I've updated my files. [2020-05-27T14:02:04,742][WARN ][logstash.filters.csv     ][main] Error parsing csv {:field=>"message", :source=>"May 6 2020 11:29:59.863,1,PPy_6XEBuZH417wO9uVe,_doc", :exception=>#<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected LogStash::Timestamp)>}

Comment: what version of logstash are you working with? and what OS are you using? clearly the error message is different as I no longer see all those ,,,,,,,,,, in the error.

Comment: v7.6.2, centos7.5. file location is /etc/test/test.csv

Comment: Hi- managed to get this working. The issue on my side was down the a change in the config that must not have been picked up. I stopped logstash and ran a daemon-reload. Thanks for the help!